# How Do I Shorten the Pull Distance on UIRefreshControl to Activate the Pull to Refresh Action?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uirefreshcontrol

Hey StackOverflow People,

I've been trying to figure out this question for some time now but to no avail and I need some help. I have a `UITableView` close to the bottom of my app and there's not enough screen distance for the user to engage the refresh. Does anybody know how I can shorten the distance it takes to activate the pull to refresh action on a `UIRefreshControl` within a `UITableView` and `UIWebView`?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can still use refreshControl but with some modifications!

add these code to your viewController:

```
var canRefresh = true

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -100 { //change 100 to whatever you want

        if canRefresh && !self.refreshControl.refreshing {

            self.canRefresh = false
            self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()

            self.refresh() // your viewController refresh function
        }
    }else if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 { 

        self.canRefresh = true
    }
}
```

and as usual in the end of your refresh logic in self.refresh() function add :

```
   self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

Comment: fantastic stuff !

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was hoping to find.

Comment: thanks for canRefresh hack. refreshcontrol size is changing randomly without it.

Comment: This should be the selected answer obviously!!

Answer (score 11):

As per the Apple Docs, I don't see any way to modify `UIRefreshControl` parameters.
link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html

Use a third-party component like [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl) (*to customize the scroll-distance in order to activate the refresh, modify* the **`#define kMaxDistance`** *constant*).

### or...

Don't use the `UIRefreshControl` and instead implement your own logic in the `-scrollViewDidScroll` method like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        //refresh logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl) have modifiable parameters that affect the pull distance? I was looking at it but didn't see anything that did. Or I could just be blind and have a terrible case of tunnel vision today.

Comment: @DanielSanchez: I haven't had the need to modify it yet. anyways, this may help: https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl/pull/9#issuecomment-17048903

Comment: @DanielSanchez aah, in the `ODRefreshControl.m` modify the `#define kMaxDistance 53` parameter. i guess that'll help

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thanks a lot! I believe this is the solution for anyone trying to do the same thing I'm doing. I just went with [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl) and modified that `#define kMaxDistance 53` constant to get my desired output. Woohoo!

Comment: @DanielSanchez : no probs :) i have edited my answer to include this _important_ bit of information

Comment: This answer would seem to be wrong now guys.  You can just call .beginRefreshing() as Ashkan explains.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3.2 and above :

```
var canRefresh = true

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -100 {
        if canRefresh && !self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
            self.canRefresh = false
            self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
            self.handleRefresh()
        }
    } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 {
        self.canRefresh = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it right with some modification

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        return refreshControl
    }()

//refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
```

every PullToRefresh must have couple lines of code like this, that handleRefresh function, do whatever you need to refresh the page.

you just need to comment out addTarget line and add this function to your code
```

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -80 { //change 80 to whatever you want
            if  !self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
                handleRefresh()
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote this code with the help of Ashkan Ghodrat's answer