# How is the pull distance calculated for a UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

Just to be clear, I don't want to change the distance, I just want to know what it is as I'm doing some other UI stuff at the same time. Is it a fixed distance or a function of the height of the associated `UITableView`?

Answer (score 4):

The pull distance seems to be very close to 50% of the `tableView` height.

FYI: You can't modify the pull distance of `UIRefreshControl`.

Check my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224153/2857130) for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the distance you use a little trick.
you can make it right with some modification

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
        return refreshControl
    }()

//refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
```

every PullToRefresh must have couple lines of code like this, that handleRefresh function, do whatever you need to refresh the page.

you just need to comment out addTarget line and add this function to your code
```

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -80 { //change 80 to whatever you want
            if  !self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
                handleRefresh()
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote this code with the help of Ashkan Ghodrat's answer